# Add numbers to axes of chart

Tags: c#, charts, openxml

So I have a fairly standard chart method using the c# `DocumentFormat.OpenXML`, namespace which works fine. But I can't figure out how to put number labels on the axes, specifically the value axis. Unfortunately the c# openxml is almost completely undocumented. I'll be happy to see an answer elsewhere if this is a duplicate question, because I can't find it. How do I add number labels to my axes?

My full code is below, but here is the part where I create the value axis, so I assume I have to add something in the parentheses here, like a `new ????` but I don't know what it is.

```
ValueAxis valAx = plotArea.AppendChild<ValueAxis>(new ValueAxis(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) },
    new Scaling(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Orientation()
    {
        Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
    }),
    new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<AxisPositionValues>(AxisPositionValues.Left) },
    new MajorGridlines(),
    new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.NumberingFormat()
    {
        FormatCode = new StringValue("General"),
        SourceLinked = new BooleanValue(true)
    }, new TickLabelPosition()
    {
        Val = new EnumValue<TickLabelPositionValues>(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo)
    }, new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112U) },
    new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossesValues>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
    new CrossBetween() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossBetweenValues>(CrossBetweenValues.Between) })
    //, new ???????() { ???? } //I think I need to add something here
    );
```

Here is the graph I'm getting now:

[image: Without number labels]

And here is how I want it to look:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
private static void InsertChartInSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetDocument document, string title, Dictionary<string, int> data)
{
    WorksheetPart graphWorksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    graphWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
    Sheets sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>() ;

    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
    {
        Id = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(graphWorksheetPart),
        SheetId = 2,
        Name = "Graph"
    };
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    // Add a new drawing to the worksheet.
    DrawingsPart drawingsPart = graphWorksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
    graphWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing()
    { Id = graphWorksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) });
    graphWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

    // Add a new chart and set the chart language to English-US.
    ChartPart chartPart = drawingsPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();
    chartPart.ChartSpace = new ChartSpace();
    chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(new EditingLanguage() { Val = new StringValue("en-US") });
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart chart = chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart>(
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart());

    // Create a new clustered column chart.
    PlotArea plotArea = chart.AppendChild<PlotArea>(new PlotArea());
    Layout layout = plotArea.AppendChild<Layout>(new Layout());
    BarChart barChart = plotArea.AppendChild<BarChart>(new BarChart(new BarDirection()
    { Val = new EnumValue<BarDirectionValues>(BarDirectionValues.Column) },
        new BarGrouping() { Val = new EnumValue<BarGroupingValues>(BarGroupingValues.Clustered) }));

    uint i = 0;

    // Iterate through each key in the Dictionary collection and add the key to the chart Series
    // and add the corresponding value to the chart Values.
    foreach (string key in data.Keys)
    {
        BarChartSeries barChartSeries = barChart.AppendChild<BarChartSeries>(new BarChartSeries(new Index()
        {
            Val = new UInt32Value(i)
        },
            new Order() { Val = new UInt32Value(i) },
            new SeriesText(new NumericValue() { Text = key })));

        StringLiteral strLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild<CategoryAxisData>(new CategoryAxisData()).AppendChild<StringLiteral>(new StringLiteral());
        strLit.Append(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value(1U) });
        strLit.AppendChild<StringPoint>(new StringPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(0U) }).Append(new NumericValue(title));

        NumberLiteral numLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values>(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values()).AppendChild<NumberLiteral>(new NumberLiteral());
        numLit.Append(new FormatCode("General"));
        numLit.Append(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value(1U) });
        numLit.AppendChild<NumericPoint>(new NumericPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(0u) }).Append(new NumericValue(data[key].ToString()));

        i++;
    }

    barChart.Append(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) });
    barChart.Append(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) });

    // Add the Category Axis.
    CategoryAxis catAx = plotArea.AppendChild<CategoryAxis>(new CategoryAxis(new AxisId()
    { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) }, new Scaling(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Orientation()
    {
        Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
    }),
        new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<AxisPositionValues>(AxisPositionValues.Bottom) },
        new TickLabelPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<TickLabelPositionValues>(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo) },
        new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768U) },
        new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossesValues>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
        new AutoLabeled() { Val = new BooleanValue(true) },
        new LabelAlignment() { Val = new EnumValue<LabelAlignmentValues>(LabelAlignmentValues.Center) },
        new LabelOffset() { Val = new UInt16Value((ushort)100) }));

    // Add the Value Axis.
    ValueAxis valAx = plotArea.AppendChild<ValueAxis>(new ValueAxis(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) },
        new Scaling(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Orientation()
        {
            Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
        }),
        new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<AxisPositionValues>(AxisPositionValues.Left) },
        new MajorGridlines(),
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.NumberingFormat()
        {
            FormatCode = new StringValue("General"),
            SourceLinked = new BooleanValue(true)
        }, new TickLabelPosition()
        {
            Val = new EnumValue<TickLabelPositionValues>(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo)
        }, new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112U) },
        new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossesValues>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
        new CrossBetween() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossBetweenValues>(CrossBetweenValues.Between) }),

        );

    // Add the chart Legend.
    Legend legend = chart.AppendChild<Legend>(new Legend(new LegendPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<LegendPositionValues>(LegendPositionValues.Right) },
        new Layout()));

    chart.Append(new PlotVisibleOnly() { Val = new BooleanValue(true) });

    // Save the chart part.
    chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();

    // Position the chart on the worksheet using a TwoCellAnchor object.
    drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new WorksheetDrawing();
    TwoCellAnchor twoCellAnchor = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.AppendChild<TwoCellAnchor>(new TwoCellAnchor());
    twoCellAnchor.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.FromMarker(new ColumnId("1"),
        new ColumnOffset("581025"),
        new RowId("1"),
        new RowOffset("114300")));
    twoCellAnchor.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.ToMarker(new ColumnId("9"),
        new ColumnOffset("276225"),
        new RowId("16"),
        new RowOffset("0")));

    // Append a GraphicFrame to the TwoCellAnchor object.
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame graphicFrame =
        twoCellAnchor.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame>(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame());
    graphicFrame.Macro = "";

    graphicFrame.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties(
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = new UInt32Value(2u), Name = "Chart 1" },
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties()));

    graphicFrame.Append(new Transform(new Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                                            new Extents() { Cx = 0L, Cy = 0L }));

    graphicFrame.Append(new Graphic(new GraphicData(new ChartReference() { Id = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart) })
    { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" }));

    twoCellAnchor.Append(new ClientData());

    // Save the WorksheetDrawing object.
    drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Save();


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attached code should get the desired look for your x and y axis.  The new code segments are surrounded with comments

```
//START NEW CODE
//END NEW CODE
```

All of the new code is in the Category and Value Axis areas towards the bottom:

```
    private static void InsertChartInSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetDocument document, string title, Dictionary<string, int> data)
    {
        WorksheetPart graphWorksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        graphWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
        Sheets sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>() ;

        Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
        {
            Id = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(graphWorksheetPart),
            SheetId = 2,
            Name = "Graph"
        };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        // Add a new drawing to the worksheet.
        DrawingsPart drawingsPart = graphWorksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
        graphWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing()
        { Id = graphWorksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) });
        graphWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

        // Add a new chart and set the chart language to English-US.
        ChartPart chartPart = drawingsPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();
        chartPart.ChartSpace = new ChartSpace();
        chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(new EditingLanguage() { Val = new StringValue("en-US") });
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart chart = chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart>(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart());

        // Create a new clustered column chart.
        PlotArea plotArea = chart.AppendChild<PlotArea>(new PlotArea());
        Layout layout = plotArea.AppendChild<Layout>(new Layout());
        BarChart barChart = plotArea.AppendChild<BarChart>(new BarChart(new BarDirection()
        { Val = new EnumValue<BarDirectionValues>(BarDirectionValues.Column) },
            new BarGrouping() { Val = new EnumValue<BarGroupingValues>(BarGroupingValues.Clustered) }));

        uint i = 0;

        // Iterate through each key in the Dictionary collection and add the key to the chart Series
        // and add the corresponding value to the chart Values.
        foreach (string key in data.Keys)
        {
            BarChartSeries barChartSeries = barChart.AppendChild<BarChartSeries>(new BarChartSeries(new Index()
            {
                Val =
 new UInt32Value(i)
            },
                new Order() { Val = new UInt32Value(i) },
                new SeriesText(new NumericValue() { Text = key })));

            StringLiteral strLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild<CategoryAxisData>(new CategoryAxisData()).AppendChild<StringLiteral>(new StringLiteral());
            strLit.Append(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value(1U) });
            strLit.AppendChild<StringPoint>(new StringPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(0U) }).Append(new NumericValue(title));

            NumberLiteral numLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values>(
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values()).AppendChild<NumberLiteral>(new NumberLiteral());
            numLit.Append(new FormatCode("General"));
            numLit.Append(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value(1U) });
            numLit.AppendChild<NumericPoint>(new NumericPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(0u) }).Append
(new NumericValue(data[key].ToString()));

            i++;
        }

        barChart.Append(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) });
        barChart.Append(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) });

        // Add the Category Axis.
        CategoryAxis catAx = plotArea.AppendChild<CategoryAxis>(new CategoryAxis(new AxisId()
        { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) }, new Scaling(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Orientation()
        {
            Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.
OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
        }),
            //START NEW CODE
            new Delete() {Val = false},
            //END NEW CODE
            new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<AxisPositionValues>(AxisPositionValues.Bottom) },
            //START NEW CODE
            new NumberingFormat() {FormatCode = "General", SourceLinked = false},
            new MajorTickMark() {Val = TickMarkValues.Outside},
            new MinorTickMark() {Val = TickMarkValues.Cross},
            //END NEW CODE
            new TickLabelPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<TickLabelPositionValues>(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo) },
            new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768U) },
            new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossesValues>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
            new AutoLabeled() { Val = new BooleanValue(true) },
            new LabelAlignment() { Val = new EnumValue<LabelAlignmentValues>(LabelAlignmentValues.Center) },
            new LabelOffset() { Val = new UInt16Value((ushort)100) },
            //START NEW CODE
            new NoMultiLevelLabels() {Val = true}
            //END NEW CODE
            ));

        // Add the Value Axis.
        ValueAxis valAx = plotArea.AppendChild<ValueAxis>(new ValueAxis(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) },
            new Scaling(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Orientation()
            {
                Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
            }),
            //START NEW CODE
            new Delete() {Val = false},
            //END NEW CODE
            new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<AxisPositionValues>(AxisPositionValues.Left) },
            new MajorGridlines(),
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.NumberingFormat()
            {
                FormatCode = new StringValue("General"),
                SourceLinked = new BooleanValue(true)
            },
            //START NEW CODE
                new MajorTickMark() {Val = TickMarkValues.Outside},
                new MinorTickMark() {Val = TickMarkValues.Cross},
            //END NEW CODE
            new TickLabelPosition()
            {
                Val = new EnumValue<TickLabelPositionValues>
(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo)
            }, new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112U) },
            new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossesValues>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
            new CrossBetween() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossBetweenValues>(CrossBetweenValues.Between) }));

        // Add the chart Legend.
        Legend legend = chart.AppendChild<Legend>(new Legend(new LegendPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<LegendPositionValues>(LegendPositionValues.Right) },
            new Layout()));

        chart.Append(new PlotVisibleOnly() { Val = new BooleanValue(true) });

        // Save the chart part.
        chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();

        // Position the chart on the worksheet using a TwoCellAnchor object.
        drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new WorksheetDrawing();
        TwoCellAnchor twoCellAnchor = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.AppendChild<TwoCellAnchor>(new TwoCellAnchor());
        twoCellAnchor.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.FromMarker(new ColumnId("1"),
            new ColumnOffset("581025"),
            new RowId("1"),
            new RowOffset("114300")));
        twoCellAnchor.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.ToMarker(new ColumnId("9"),
            new ColumnOffset("276225"),
            new RowId("16"),
            new RowOffset("0")));

        // Append a GraphicFrame to the TwoCellAnchor object.
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame graphicFrame =
            twoCellAnchor.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.
Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame>(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.
Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame());
        graphicFrame.Macro = "";

        graphicFrame.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties(
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = new UInt32Value(2u), Name = "Chart 1" },
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties()));

        graphicFrame.Append(new Transform(new Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                                                new Extents() { Cx = 0L, Cy = 0L }));

        graphicFrame.Append(new Graphic(new GraphicData(new ChartReference() { Id = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart) })
        { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" }));

        twoCellAnchor.Append(new ClientData());

        // Save the WorksheetDrawing object.
        drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Save();


    }
```

I used the OpenXML Productivity Tool to compare your generated file with a similar one that contained the axis details.  With the compare, you can see which calls are needed to add to the plain axis in order to turn on the markings.

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I need. I can't check it today but when I do I'll accept your answer assuming it works.

Comment: And thanks for telling me about the openxml productivity tool

Comment: OK, I corrected a small error in my answer.  I just double checked it on an empty spreadsheet and it works per your requirements.

Comment: @Taterhead, thank you for this answer, it is very helpful. I need to do more changes to the chart than was asked in this question, do you know of a good place to find documentation on how to do this?

Comment: Hi @dmoore1181 - so there is not a good central place with documentation.  Here is a general strategy:  Take your original excel file with graph before your desired change:  name it orig.xslx.  Then make your desired changes to it with excel and save it new as new.xslx.  Load the two files in the OpenXML Productivity Tool and diff the files.  The tool will generate the code needed to make new.xslx and also highlight the differences.  If you would like to discuss further what you need to do, we can take this to SO chat or you create a github repo and Ill try and take a look at it.  reply here.

Comment: @Taterhead, thank you for the suggestion to use the productivity tool, it looks very promising.